# Fermion version of Gauss-Milgram sum?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-insulators

For Bosonic topological order, a very useful formula was proved to be true:

$\sum_a d_a^2 \theta_a=\mathcal{D} \exp(\frac{c_-}{8}2\pi i) $

(for more detail: $d_a$ is the quantum dimension of anyon labeled by a, and $\theta_a$ is the topological spin.D is the total quantum dimension, $\mathcal{D}^2=\sum_a d_a^2$. And $c_-$ is the chiral central charge. If we assume bulk boundary correspondence, $c_-$ can be defined as $c_-=c_L-c_R$, the chiral combination of the central charge of boundary CFT. Alternatively, the chiral central charge is also well defined without referring to CFT, that is via the thermal Hall effect when we have an edge termination.)

So my question is straightforward: what's the fermionic version of this formula?

Answer (score 3):

We just posted a paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04673  addressing this issue. 
For fermion topological orders, the fermionic version of this formula is $\Theta=\sum_a d_a^2 \theta_a=0$. See eq. 14 of the paper.  So we cannot use eq. 14 to compute the chiral central charge of the fermionic topological orders. We have to use the bosonic extension of the fermionic topological orders to computer the chiral central charge of the fermionic topological orders.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Wen. I added comments in the MO Post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209975/gauss-milgram-formula-for-fermionic-topological-order/211854#211854 I found MO is more active than Phys.SE